# Spectrum: Polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

It is written in Bratteli-Robinson that some simple transformations yield the relations:
$$\sigma(a+A)=a+\sigma(A)$$
$$\sigma(A^n)\subseteq\sigma(A)^n$$
The latter one is deduced by the transformation:
$$\lambda^n-A^n=\ldots=(\lambda-A)(\ldots)$$
Then I guess the result follows by:
$$C\text{ invertible }\iff A,B\text{ invertible }\qquad\text{for }C=AB$$
How do I prove this corollary?
Is there a similar trick for the former relation?

...oh, actually the corollary above is wrong:
Neither the right shift nor the left shift operator are invertible but their composite: $\mathbb{1}=LR$
Since the corollary only holds in the finite dimensional case (if at all) then the argumentation followed in their book is not right.

Comment: It's probably wise to define $\sigma$, $a$, $A$, and $\lambda$, especially with false statements and lots of ...

Comment: You mean by rather considering the resolvent then the spectrum? Yes but how?

Comment: @Freeze_S It does not sound like you read the comment at all. We would like you to explain what $\sigma$, $a$, $A$, and $\lambda$ are.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I missunderstood his comment ...$\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is in element in the algebra $\sigma(A)$ is its spectrum $\rho(A)$ is its resolvent set $a\in\mathbb{C}$ is a fixed number and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is a variable number in either the spectrum or the resolvent set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $C=AB$ and $AB=BA$. Then what can you say?

Comment: Haa ^^ I read that in the proof but don't know what I can say then ...A and B commute?

Comment: No wait then $ABC^{-1}=\mathbb{1}=C^{-1}BA$ and then?

Comment: If you have a left inverse $DA=I$ and a right inverse $AE=I$, then $E=(DA)E=D(AE)=DI=D$ is an inverse.

Comment: Right ...how do u prove now the above relations?

Comment: You already did with$A(BC^{-1})=I$ and $(C^{-1}B)A=I$.